# Setting the AmCharts colors Globally

Tags: amcharts

When using AmCharts let's say Pie chart, there are out of the box colors applied to the items which is not spread correctly and colors of the same family are sequentially applied which makes the charts with large number of items look pretty odd.
The sequence is always "red" first, then dark orange, light orange, yellow, 2 greens, 3 blues, etc.

I'd like to change this pattern a bit, is there a global setting for configuring this in AmCharts 3?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this use property “colors” of AmCoordinateChart object, as described here: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCoordinateChart#colors

AmCoordinateChart is the parent object of AmChart What this means in practice is that when you define your chart (by .makeChart or other means), you add a “color” property with your array of colors to the AmChart object.

If the chart requires more colors than specified in the array, then AmCharts generates extra colors automatically. So you can both change the pattern, as you request, and extend it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think you missed the point that the setting needs to be GLOBAL, not for individual charts.
In a massive project, it is virtually impossible to update each and every chart used.

Comment: @sam360 Indeed, I missed that. We generate all charts in the same code in our app, so it is a global setting for me :) I wonder if modifying .colors property for the parent class will make any difference—I can't actually try that today, but it is one possible way.

Comment: No, sorry, that doesn't seem to do much. You can change the colors array in the amcharts.js file, if you're desperate, but it is not a good idea, and you'll be forced to do it with every library update. I guess you could also make a simple wrapper for the charts and add .colors[] on every call—yet that could be a huge task depending on how much code you already have calling the chart.